# Grid view values are not binding when paginate

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

In the below code i have a grid when i try to paginate it throws page index changing error so i tried to fix that issue.But Now when i paginate it is not binding the values.So anyone help me to solve the issue.

```
<asp:GridView 
 OnPageIndexChanging="grdsrchlst_PageIndexChanging" ID="grdsrchlst" runat="server"
 PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" PageSize="10" PagerStyle-Visible="true"
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

code:

```
protected void grdsrchlst_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdsrchlst.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    SearchInformation(DataTable dtSearch); //Throws error ...i cant bind the value when paginate
}

public void SearchInformation(DataTable dtSearch)
{ 
    grdsrchlst.DataSource = dtSearch;
    grdsrchlst.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Where are you keeping the datatable while the postbacks occur?

Answer (score 0):

The `dtSearch` value will be `null` at `grdsrchlst_PageIndexChanging` event.

Load the `dtSearch` first and then try binding.

Comment: My issue is i cant call SearchInformation(DataTable dtSearch); from grdsrchlst_PageIndexChanging() it throws error on parameters (DataTable dtSearch)

Comment: Thats why, first populate `dtSearch` with the values. I mean, if there is a code something like `dtSearch = ` then call that first and call `SearchInformation(DataTable dtSearch);`

Comment: when it is in 1st page all the values are binded when it moves to next page i cant call the binding method.

Comment: It depends on the page life cycle.Any server side events will cause `PostBack`. Any `PostBack` will run the code behind from the beginning, initializing all the public and private variables to its original values. In your case `dtSearch` will loose its value on page change event. So you need to get the values once again and bind it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the way you are calling your SearchInformation() function in grdsrchlst_PageIndexChanging. You are declaring a new parameter dtSearch in the call itself hence it will be shoot an error as it is not initialized.

Try initializing the dataTable like below

```
protected void grdsrchlst_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            grdsrchlst.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

            //Initialize dtSearch
            DataTable dtSearch = new DataTable();
            SearchInformation(dtSearch);
        }
```

In the given code though you have initialized dtSearch, it still does not have any value hence your gird will not be displayed. Secondly, I observed you have 'AutoGenerateColumns' parameter of your grid set to false. So unless you have added columns to your gridview at some place in your code, the grid will not be displayed if binded with datatable with no values or columns.

Here is sample code I wrote that works

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CSharpWebFormTrials._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView 
            OnPageIndexChanging="grdsrchlst_PageIndexChanging"
            ID="grdsrchlst" runat="server" PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages"
            PageSize="10" PagerStyle-Visible="true" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AllowPaging="True" Visible="true">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code behind is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace CSharpWebFormTrials
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtSearch = fillData();
            SearchInformation(dtSearch);

            //Store in viewstate
            ViewState["dtSearch"] = dtSearch;

            //Store in Session
            //Session["dtSearch"] = dtSearch;
        }

        protected void grdsrchlst_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            grdsrchlst.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

            //Initialize the dtSearch variable
            //DataTable dtSearch = new DataTable();

            //Alternately you can fill the data
            //DataTable dtSearch = fillData();

            //Access vuewstate
            DataTable dtSearch;
            if (ViewState["dtSearch"] != null)
            {
                dtSearch = (DataTable)ViewState["dtSearch"];
            }
            else
            {
                dtSearch = fillData();
            }

            //Access Sessiop
            //if (Session["dtSearch"] != null)
            //{
            //    dtSearch = (DataTable)Session["dtSearch"];
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    dtSearch = fillData();
            //}

            SearchInformation(dtSearch);
        }

        public void SearchInformation(DataTable dtSearch)
        {
            grdsrchlst.DataSource = dtSearch;
            grdsrchlst.DataBind();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Filling the dataTable with Dummy data
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns> 
        /// Filled dataTable
        /// </returns>

        public DataTable fillData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Col1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Col2");
            dt.Columns.Add("Col3");
            dt.Columns.Add("Col4");

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(i, i, i, i);
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

I am a beginner myself, so experts please comment if I have passed on any wrong information.

Comment: @user3319384: Edited to show examples of using viewstate and session

Answer (score 0):

;Stick the DataTable in ViewState when you first populate it and retrieve it from ViewState and rebind each time you change the paging.

```
ViewState["dtSearch"] = dtSearch;
```

Then, when postbacks occur when you are moving through the PageIndex - you get the DataTable back by writing:

```
dtSearch = (DataTable)ViewState["dtSearch"];
```

Comment: Can u pls provide some example for Stick the DataTable in ViewState

Comment: (How do you write code in a reply like this on this site?) When you first populate your DataTable, you write: ViewState["dtSearch"] = dtSearch; Then, when postbacks occur when you are moving through the PageIndex - you get the DataTable back by writing: DataTable dtSearch = (DataTable)ViewState["dtSearch"]. It is that simple.